# После отправки формы остаться на той же странице

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, route

Добрый день

В app/view/layouts есть форма обратной связи, которая отображается на всех страницах приложения

1. Как сделать, чтобы после отправки формы пользователь остался на той странице, на которой он этой формой воспользовался?

(пока сделан переход на главную страницу:

```
def feedback
   @name = params[:mail_body][:name]
   @phone = params[:mail_body][:phone]
   @comment = params[:mail_body][:comment]
   FeedbackMailer.feedback_email
   render public_main_index_path
end
```

)

2. Как правильно задать маршрут? 
   в routes.rb пока прописано так:

   ```
   post '/', :controller => 'public/main', :action => 'feedback'
   ```

и форма отправляется только с главной страницы

Код формы

```
    = form_for :mail_body do |f|
      = f.text_field :name, :placeholder => "Имя"
      = f.text_field :phone, :placeholder => "Телефон"
      = f.text_area :comment, :placeholder => "Комментарий"
      = f.submit type: "submit", name:"action"
```

Спасибо

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вообще, есть такая опция:

   redirect_to :back

Кстати

> пока сделан переход на главную страницу:
>   `render public_main_index_path`

У меня это не работает и не уверен в том, как это должно работать.

2. Видимо так:

   post '/', to: 'public/main#feedback'

Но я бы не стал подмешивать лишние экшены к корневому урлу.
Лучше сделать отдельный урл, а оттуда либо редиректить (см. пункт 1), либо вообще отвечать аяксом без перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: вот сейчас с аяксом пытаюсь разобраться

Answer (score 3):

В `routes.rb`:

```
get 'feedback', to: 'public/main#feedback'
post 'feedback', to: 'public/main#feedback_send'
```

В контроллере:

```
def feedback

end

def feedback_send
  # такая-то логика
  render :feedback
end
```

Форма

```
= form_for :mail_body, url: feedback_path, method: 'post' do |f|
  = f.text_field :name, :placeholder => "Имя"
  = f.text_field :phone, :placeholder => "Телефон"
  = f.text_area :comment, :placeholder => "Комментарий"
  = f.submit type: "submit", name:"action"
```

Comment: на строчку render :feedback выскакивает Missing template public/main/feedback, application/feedback with ....

Comment: @KakaoBaba ну, тогда сделай рендер существующего шаблона. Того, где написано "Спасибо что связались с нами", или подобного.